# Log file for mysql database

Tags: mysql

How can I create a log file for mysql, and maintain the log for each database transaction?

Comment: Have you actually searched for this on Google? The first result for "mysql logging" is pretty much perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of [MySQL logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html). If you're just after a record of changes, the binary log should be ideal for your requirements.

Information on log maintenance is also reference from the page linked above.